# strange behavior in event page: TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I try to do this in an event page.

```
// When the browser action is clicked, call the
// getBm function.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getBm);


function getBm () {
    var url = 'test.html';
    dumpBookmarks();
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: url });  
}


function dumpBookmarks() {
    var b = chrome.bookmarks.getTree(
        function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
            console.log(bookmarkTreeNodes); --------(1)
        });
}

function dumpTreeNodes(bookmarkNodes) {
   //do something here    
}
```

This works fine but if I try to do

```
console.log(dumpTreeNodes(bookmarkTreeNodes));
```

at (1) it throws error,

```
Error in response to bookmarks.getTree: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 34 and 38. You've probably got an error in your own code. Could you provide a complete steps-to-reproduce, or make a screencast that shows the bug in action?

Comment: Strange.. it was showing this error because of a syntactical error in `//do something here`.

Comment: FYI the confusing error was caused by missing stack frames in the stack trace (https://crbug.com/404406). This has been corrected in Chrome 39.